# Hsql unexpected token: IF

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I'm new to Hsql,

I try to run a script :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'table') AND type in      (N'U'))
BEGIN
DROP TABLE table
END ;
```

Hsql complains about the IF keyword:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: IF : line: 2
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone could help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of procedural language is not supported by HSQLDB.

Try this:

```
 DROP TABLE MYTABLE IF EXISTS
```